# Laplace and Fourier transform

Tags: laplace-transform, fourier-transform

If I have a partial differential equation ( diffusivity eq. With distance (x) variable on the left and time (t) variable on the left ) for example with some given conditions , what is the right procedure (steps) to solve it ? 
Should I apply FT to the x-part and LT to t-part or are they exchanged?
Can you clarify more?

Comment: I mean... that depends on the equation.

Comment: There are some common steps to solve it